# Error during Publish AWS Serverless Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

We are using AWS Toolkit Visual Studio 2017("https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/preview-of-the-aws-toolkit-for-visual-studio-2017/") for create AWS Serverless lambda. When we deploy this lambda function we get the status: "UPDATE_ROLLBACK_Complete"

[image]

Here is our serverless.template file:

```js
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
  "Transform" : "AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31",
  "Description" : "An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.",

  "Parameters" : {
    
  },

  "Conditions" : {
    
  },

  "Resources" : {

  "Get" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
        "Handler": "F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.IdentityServer::F2C.MAP.API.AWSLambda.IdentityServer.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
        "Runtime": "dotnetcore2.0",
        "CodeUri": "",
  "FunctionName":"CreateToken",
  "Description":"Create access token based on clientId and client secret",
        "MemorySize": 256,
        "Timeout": 30,
        "Role": null,
        "Policies": [ "AWSLambdaFullAccess" ],
        "Environment" : {
          "Variables" : {
            
          }
        },
  "VpcConfig":{
   "SecurityGroupIds":["sg-123456"],
   "SubnetIds":["subnet-123456"]
  },
        "Events": {
          "PutResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "GET"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
  },

  "Outputs" : {
    
  }
}
```

Comment: You checked 'Rollback on Failure' and this status was the result of rollback. But this said nothing about your error.

Comment: Issue is fixed, actually we have to pass valid role if our lambda use another resources inside VPC.